# MVC disable submit button till form is validate

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am new in MVC4. 
can any one tell me how do is disable submit button until it the form didn't pass the validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this - you should do client validation, because server-side validation runs *after* pressing submit button. So, implement your client validation and use jQuery to show/hide submit button, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (validate()) {
        $('#your-submit-button-id').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#your-submit-button-id').hide();
    }
});
```

And implement your validation using keypress event (for example)